# Error Installing JSON 1.8.1 via RubyGems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My OS is Windows 7 64x Ultimate. I try to install the json gem like this:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

But I have a problem:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150220-2012-1uff8mn.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

How can install json 1.8.1?

Comment: What does C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.1/gem_make.out say?

Comment: What version of rubygems are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug with Rubygems. Take a look at the [issue page for this bug](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977) over on github.

It has not yet been fixed but will hopefully be fixed soon. For now, it seems most people have to **downgrade to rubygems 2.3.0** to get it to work on Windows. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your ruby gem to the newest version

To check what your ruby in now

```
$Ruby -v
```

Update it to ruby version 2.3.7

```
$rvm list known
$rvm install 2.3.7
$rvm use 2.3.7 --default
$gem install bundler
```

Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsNXc3uQ2AA&lc=z22pvls4asawvhi5004t1aokgq0e4p2vb1qpp3w3z252bk0h00410.1528974099408204
Let me know if does that help!