# Heroku Deploy Failed | gem install json -v '1.8.1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my ROR application to heroku, but getting this error constantly. I downgraded my Ruby version to 2.3.0. This is what I have on my Gemfile.lock

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0p0

BUNDLED WITH

### 1.16.2

But I still get the below error and also heroku always trying to use the Ruby version 2.4.4 and bundler 1.15.2 even though my lock file has the different version.

remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          dropzonejs-rails was resolved to 0.7.0, which depends on
remote:            rails was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
remote:              actionmailer was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
remote:                actionpack was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
remote:                  actionview was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
remote:                    activesupport was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
remote:                      json

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you downgraded your ruby version ? did you push the your latest code on master branch ?

Comment: yes. I did push the code. As referred to this link and downgraded the Ruby Version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635918/error-installing-json-1-8-1-via-rubygems

Comment: the question was asked in Feb 2015 . in 2018 you don't need to downgrade you ruby version. downgrading your ruby version will create lots of problems. can you please try to use your previous and stable version of ruby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reverting to Ruby 2.4.4 because that is the current default version used by Heroku. This suggests that Ruby 2.3.0 is no longer supported. Check out Heroku's [ruby version support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions) page for more information.

Revert back to the Ruby version you were using and run

`$ bundle update && bundle install`

Then try pushing to heroku

Answer (score 0):

To check what your ruby in now

```
$Ruby -v
```

Update it to the newest ruby version 2.3.7

```
$rvm list known
$rvm install 2.3.7
$rvm use 2.3.7 --default
$gem install bundler
```

Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsNXc3uQ2AA&lc=z22pvls4asawvhi5004t1aokgq0e4p2vb1qpp3w3z252bk0h00410.1528974099408204
Let me know if does that help!